# how to integrate default app of android in our app programatically

Tags: android

Is it possible to integrate the default app(like **Calendar**) of Android  in our app programatically .
Can anyone explain me in details....

The two classes that I am using are:
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Example.readCalendar(this);
    }
}
```

and another class **Example.java**

```
public class Example {

    public static void readCalendar(Context context) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        // Fetch a list of all calendars synced with the device, their display names and whether the
        // user has them selected for display.

        final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"),
                (new String[] { "_id", "displayName", "selected" }), null, null, null);
        // For a full list of available columns see http://tinyurl.com/yfbg76w

        HashSet<String> calendarIds = new HashSet<String>();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            final String _id = cursor.getString(0);
            final String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
            final Boolean selected = !cursor.getString(2).equals("0");

            System.out.println("Id: " + _id + " Display Name: " + displayName + " Selected: " + selected);
            calendarIds.add(_id);
        }

        // For each calendar, display all the events from the previous week to the end of next week.        
        for (String id : calendarIds) {
            Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
            long now = new Date().getTime();
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, now - DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS);
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, now + DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS);

            Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(),
                    new String[] { "title", "begin", "end", "allDay"}, "Calendars._id=" + id,
                    null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC"); 
            // For a full list of available columns see http://tinyurl.com/yfbg76w

            while (eventCursor.moveToNext()) {
                final String title = eventCursor.getString(0);
                final Date begin = new Date(eventCursor.getLong(1));
                final Date end = new Date(eventCursor.getLong(2));
                final Boolean allDay = !eventCursor.getString(3).equals("0");

                System.out.println("Title: " + title + " Begin: " + begin + " End: " + end +
                        " All Day: " + allDay);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I have added the READ_CALENDAR permission also.

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: I mean if I want to use the default calendar app or some other default app of Android in my application programtically. how its possible ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These articles might help you.

1. [Working with the Android Calendar](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar-3850276.htm)
2. [Accessing the internal calendar database inside Google Android applications](http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151)
3. [Calendar API (android.provider.Calendar)](http://www.anddev.org/calendar_api_androidprovidercalendar-t2236.html)

Example :

```
static String contentProvider;
static Uri remindersUri;
static Uri eventsUri;
static Uri calendars;

if(Build.VERSION.RELEASE.contains(”2.2″))
    contentProvider = “com.android.calendar”;
else
    contentProvider = “calendar”;

remindersUri = Uri.parse(String.format(”content://%s/reminders”,contentProvider));
eventsUri = Uri.parse(String.format(”content://%s/events”,contentProvider));
calendars = Uri.parse(String.format(”content://%s/calendars”,contentProvider));
```

Comment: I used the second article as it looked most appropriate . Its working  on the device but not showing the calendar also. Any Idea..?

Comment: If you could give me an idea what you are trying to accomplish , i may be able to help you better :)

Comment: I just want to show the default calendar and control its event  through my app. Hope you got my point..

Comment: Which content provider are you using                              Content provider URI
Old: content://calendar/
New: content://com.android.calendar/

Comment: in the above code , replace "content://calendar/" with "content://com.android.calendar/"

Comment: Check this website too : http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/02/insertion-and-deletion-of-calendar.html

Comment: i have checked by replacing "content://calendar/" with "content://com.android.calendar/"  but this time, it does not even run on device throwing some exception. Earlier it was running on the device but not showing the calendar.

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");
intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", eventStartInMillis);
intent.putExtra("endTime", eventEndInMillis);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Could not get you . What actually we can do with the above code.can you explain it..?