# Launching default android launcher programmatically

Tags: android, launcher

I'm looking for a way to launch the default android launcher programatically,
something perhaps like the code below. Or do I have to add something to the manifest file?
Thanks!

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.launcher", "Launcher");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547606/how-to-integrate-default-app-of-android-in-our-app-programatically

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER));
```

(I haven't tried it myself, because my use case is a little more complicated---I've replaced the launcher, and I want to call the *old* launcher...)

I've also discovered that you can use the package manager to look through all activities that meet some intent filter criteria. For example, if you want to find all the activities marked as the home default home activity, use this:

```
Intent intent=null;
final PackageManager packageManager=getPackageManager();
for(final ResolveInfo resolveInfo:packageManager.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME), PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY))
{
    if(!getPackageName().equals(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName))  //if this activity is not in our activity (in other words, it's another default home screen)
    {
        intent=packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName));
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that I have replaced the default home screen on my device---that's why I have to make sure the activity I found is not the activity that's running! If you haven't replaced the default home activity, you don't need this check---just use the first (and probably the only) default home activity.

(Note that I still can't launch the old launcher from my launcher, perhaps because the old launcher keeps a record of the default launcher, which is my new launcher, and simply calls back to it. I don't know. But at least it doesn't crash, and I would guess that, if you haven't replaced the old home screen, it just might work.)

Comment: Please note that the getLaunchIntentForPackage method will not return the launcher intent since it only checks for INFO and LAUNCH categories while the Laucher has the HOME category in intent. This means that the call in the if inside the for will return a null intent. Replacing the intent initialization with the code below did the trick for me.    intent = new Intent().addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME).setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
      .setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);

Comment: hey @GarretWilson, did you figure out how to launch the non-default launcher?

Comment: @isaganiesteron, sorry, I haven't touched this code in years. I don't have any updates at the moment.

Comment: To start the stock launcher, add this: `    intent.setPackage("com.android.launcher");`

Answer (score 4):

Following Garret Wilson's answer, here's an ugly one-liner, assuming `context` is your application context:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME).setPackage(context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME), PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).get(0).activityInfo.packageName));
```

This code assumes that the original system home activity is always the first result returned by `queryIntentActivities`, whereas the accepted answer returns the first home activity not belonging to the running package.

It's still unclear how to cleanly get the system home activity. Some threads mention that `getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, flags)` can be used for this, but it seems `PackageManager.MATCH_SYSTEM_ONLY` cannot be used with this method.

Comment: The system home activity can be distinguished from the others by comparing it´s signature with any other known system app: both will have the same SHA1 hash.

Answer (score 1):

```
=> In kotlin add below code in onDestroy method of appCompactActvity use to make your app as default launcher, 

override fun onDestroy() {
        var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        var packageManager: PackageManager = packageManager
        for (resolveInfo in packageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME), PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)) {
            if (packageName != resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName)  //if this activity is not in our activity (in other words, it's another default home screen)
            {
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            break
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 startActivity( Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can open the app launcher,

```html
   
Intent intentf = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ALL_APPS);
intentf.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intentf);
```