# Is it somehow possible to send Activity onPause() progragmatically?

Tags: android, onpause, activity-lifecycle

I have done my research.
It seems not possible.

I need my Activity to go onPause() programmatically from onResume(), click a button and go *somehow* onPause(),
without using onKeyDown()...

I know, probably impossible... maybe somebody has some tweak for that,
or maybe not.

Thank you anyway

Comment: Why do you want to call `onPause()` if your `Activity` is still showing? Maybe we can help find a better way to achieve what you want if you explain your intentions

Comment: The key is that onPause() normally happens because something else is taking over the user interaction.  So the way to make onPause() happen is to use an Intent to bring up whatever you want to happen instead.

Comment: @Chris Stratton thank you. Please what kind of intent do you advise I could use, without losing visibility of the Activity?

Comment: An intent to a transparent activity... but if you want the current activity to remain visible, why pause it?

Comment: @codeMagic Thank you for your kind availability. For the time being that would be what I need...I know it is not easy...thank you again

Comment: My concern is that it sounds like you just want your app to sit and do nothing while the user stares at a static screen...probably not a good idea. As I said, I'm sure there is a better way to do what you need if you explained a little better. Even a progress dialog or something so the user doesn't think/feel that your app is froze

Comment: @ChrisStratton an intent to a transparent Activity would do the magic?!?!!!!! I thought that the Activity would not go onPause() as long as it is visible...

Comment: onStart()/onStop() concern (at least partially) visible lifetime, while onResume()/onPause() concern interactive lifetime.  But you still haven't explained why you want to do this odd thing or what you hope to achieve from it - which is important, because it's hard to imagine cases where this would be the proper solution.

Comment: @codeMagic indeed codeM that is what I need, the user to stare at a static screen :-) I am trying to do so a Lockscreen

Comment: That's a terrible way to make a lock screen!  The user can just hit the home or recents or back key and leave your silly application behind.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I will need to override onKeyDown() to avoid that "navigation away". Anyway there are not many alternatives for doing a lock screen, without touching the firmware.

Comment: @pietmau so you want to close your "lock screen?" Just call finish() - that will destroy it.

Comment: @DoctororDrive it does not work, if I do so the system would call the stock lock screen...thank you anyway!!!

Comment: The ultimate point is that you cannot make a lock screen in a normal application.  Voting to close as not a real question, because the original question is not answerable and the goal from comments not achievable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton please have a look at this https://sites.google.com/site/paranoidandroidproject/

Comment: That's not a lock screen application, it's just a trick to get a small amount of information onto the stock lock screen "The gory details: Contact Owner works by changing the text for the next alarm"

Comment: @ChrisStratton I know Chris, it is a dirty trick, but if is all that is possible...

Comment: It's a trick that is completely and totally unrelated to your question.  If you wanted to display some information on the stock lock screen, then you should have asked about that, or just used the code which you found, though beware it may not be futureproof.

Comment: @ChrisStratton maybe you are right. Thank you anywy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can "pause" Activity from it's code.
You can either close it by calling

```
finish()
```

or start a new Activity that will take the foreground - then you'll get it paused, but that's not what you want.

I have never done a lock screen myself. There is really not much information, the Android is not designed to have third party lock screens apk's, so it might get really tricky if it's possible.

What I suspect you have to do is to call a Launcher to hide your Activity, you can try this

[Launching default android launcher programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705847/launching-default-android-launcher-programmatically)

If it won't work, you can look at the code by the links provided in that question's answer. Good luck!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864300/create-a-lock-screen-of-my-own

Answer (score 1):

The onPause() method from Activity are managed by the UIThread, the main thread of your App. So you can't call it programmatically. If you want to call onPause() method, you need to call another activity over your current Activity.

Comment: thank you very much ! Do you think it could be a "transparent" Activity like Chris suggested?

Comment: Yes, but you can't keep the user from navigating away from / uninstalling that activity.

Comment: @ChrisStratton of course you are right !